# When returning Promise then, but getting `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Promise<number>'`

Tags: typescript, promise

I am trying to make function that returns Promise or Normal Value.

```
type Flow1 = <T, U>(a: T | Promise<T>, f: (a: T) => U) => U | Promise<U>

export const flow1: Flow1 = (a, f) => (a instanceof Promise ? a.then(f) : f(a))

flow1(Promise.resolve(4), (n) => n ** 2).then(console.log)

// Property 'then' does not exist on type 'number | Promise<number>'
```

But I get error when chaining then to the function.
I have no idea what is wrong with this typing.

#### Added

```
export function flow1<T, U>(a: T, f: (a: T) => U): U {
  return f(a)
}
export function flow2<T, U>(a: Promise<T>, f: (a: T) => U): Promise<U> {
  return a.then(f)
}

flow1(1, (n) => n ** 2)
flow2(Promise.resolve(1), (n) => n ** 2).then(console.log)
```

Okay is there any way to overload with same function name? :(

Comment: Try to use typescript overloadings. If argument is promise- return promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the `flow1` function can, *inside it*, distinguish the difference between an `a` argument that's a Promise and a plain value, TS doesn't allow the inference to propagate *outside*.

You'll have to examine the return value to see if you can call `.then` on it:

```
type Flow1 = <T, U>(a: T | Promise<T>, f: (a: T) => U) => U | Promise<U>

export const flow1: Flow1 = (a, f) => (a instanceof Promise ? a.then(f) : f(a))

const result = flow1(Promise.resolve(4), (n) => n ** 2);
if (result instanceof Promise) {
  result.then(console.log);
}
```

You could also use overloading, but it involves quite some boilerplate:

```
type Flow1 = {
    <T, U>(a: T, f: (a: T) => U): void;
    <T, U>(a: Promise<T>, f: (a: T) => U): Promise<U>;
};
const flow1: Flow1 = <T, U>(a: T | Promise<T>, f: (a: T) => U) => (a instanceof Promise ? a.then(f) : f(a));
flow1(Promise.resolve(4), (n: number) => n ** 2).then(console.log)
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to write overloading with `function` expression?
Is there any way to achieve this?
Like

```ts
function flow1(): T
function flow1(): Promise<T> {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You mean without the separate `type`? It'd be really ugly, but basically, just copy-paste the type contents over the `Flow1`. `const flow1: { <T, U>(a: T, f: (a: T) => U): void;` etc. Too hard to read.